# Is there any way to get the classes from System.Collections.Concurrent in .NET 3.5?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, collections, concurrency

The question pretty much says it all.

Does anyone know of any way to get the collection classes from the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace in .NET 3.5?

I guess what I'm asking is whether anyone has gone through the trouble of porting these classes to their own DLL that could be accessed from .NET 3.5.

Comment: Using Reflector ... wait, what is the question?

Comment: http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Concurrent/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: The reactive extensions library doesn't appear to be offered for .NET 3.5 anymore, sadly. However, if you can find an older version of the library, it definitely did contain backports of the concurrent collection classes for .NET 3.5. I know because *I used them extensively* at a previous company.

---

I just discovered this by accident.

It turns out these collections were available all along through [Microsoft's Reactive Extensions (Rx) library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx), which is available for .NET 3.5, and which in fact **I have been using already** for some time (just never realized they were there).

The `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace is provided by System.Threading.dll.

Just posting this here for posterity.

Comment: Rx Library is only for .NET 4 now. And even the old library I can't find System.Collections.Concurrent.

Comment: @JosephKingry: Sorry, at the time I posted this they offered it for 3.5, and the old version definitely offered the concurrent collections (I used them quite a bit). I guess your best bet now would be to either upgrade to 4.0 or try to find an old version of Rx!

Answer (score 3):

No, they are in the 4.0 version of `System.dll`. So trying to pull that in to a 3.5 app would not work.

Comment: I just discovered that they in fact *are* available in .NET 3.5, as part of the Rx extensions library.

Comment: @Dan great! There is nothing I know of in those classes that are dependent on the 4.0 runtime, so the implementation could be copied into any 3.5 assembly.

Answer (score 3):

I used the [Task Parallel Library for .NET 3.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary). Works great.

The package includes:

- Task for executing asynchronous operations.
- Concurrent Collections such as ConcurrentStack, ConcurentQueue ad ConcurrentDictionary.
- PLINQ for writing parallel queries.
- additional Threading operations such as Barrier,SpinLock and SpinWait.